# React Chunk download background

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

In my react app production build i need a chunk to be downloaded in the browser in background.
The issue is that currently when i click a button it will start "await" for an import operation of the module and wait for the browser to have that chunk.
Since this module in is a functional module it's not related to any component hence i can't use code splitting.

```
export const dialog_xlsx_array_create = async (raw, head) => {
  const Excel = await import('exceljs/modern.browser');
  let xlsxarray = [];
<----some operations--->
```

the above function is only called when i click a button.
but this module is almost 1 Mb.
I need this module to be downloaded by the browser in background (can't bundle it with main chunk due to size issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [use the webpack magic comment “prefetch”](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prefetchingpreloading-modules) to instruct the browser to download this chunk during idle time:

```
import(/* webpackPrefetch: true */ 'exceljs/modern.browser');
```

This will add a prefetch link to your head tag when your main module including this dynamic import had loaded